# Prove $\inf\{d(k,x) |\, x\in A\}$ exists

Tags: real-analysis

Given a non-empty set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^p$ and a point $k\in \mathbb{R}^p $. For all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^p$ de define the distance as $d(x,y)= ||x-y||$, (euclidean metric). 
Prove that
\begin{align}
\inf\{d(k,x) | x\in A\}
\end{align}
exists.

$A$ could be open. If this is the case then for all $x\in A, x$ is an interior point, so there will always be a point in $A$ that is closer to $k$. I don't understand why $\inf\{d(k,x) | x\in A\}$ exists, if $A$ is open. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: the infimum of a set of real numbers exists if and only if the set is non-empty and bounded below

Answer (score 2):

The set of reals $\mathcal A=\{d(k,x) \mid x \in A\}$ is bounded below by zero as the distance is always non negative.

It is also non empty as soon as $A$ itself is not empty. It is then a theorem about the real line that $\mathcal A$ has an infimum. **Which doesn’t mean that such infimum is attained.**

Answer (score 1):

This follows directly from completeness axiom, which claims

> Any non-empty set $ A \subset \mathbb{R} $ which is bounded below has an infinum.

The reasoning is as follows:

1. The set $ \lbrace d(k,x) \mid x \in A \rbrace $ is non-empty as $ A $ is non-empty.
2. The set is bounded below by 0 (distance between two points is non-negative).